# The argument type Future<User?> can´t be assigned to the parameter type Future<User>?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i'm trying to validate the user but i got this error

```
The argument type 'Future<User?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<User>?'
```

this is my code

```
home: FutureBuilder<User>(
            future: Auth.getCurrentUser(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> userSnapshot) {
              if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                if (userSnapshot.error != null) {
                  print("error");
                  return Text(userSnapshot.error.toString());
                }
                return userSnapshot.hasData
                    ? Home(userSnapshot.data!.uid)
                    : Welcome();
              } else {
                return Text(
                  "Tabs",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                );
              }
          },
        ),
```

Auth.getCurrentUser() It is a function that the user returns, this is the code

```
static Future<User?> getCurrentUser() async {
    User? user =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return user;
  }
```

Comment: In this function, if you do not use await removing async not needed
Else return future value like
return Future<int>.value(user);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change

```
home: FutureBuilder<User>(
```

to

```
home: FutureBuilder<User?>(
```